# Issue mounting Cloud SQL credentials to a container in Kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm attempting to migrate over to Cloud SQL (Postgres). I have the following deployment in Kubernetes, having followed these instructions https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-container-engine :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: menu-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: menu-service
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
          secret:
            secretName: cloudsql-instance-credentials
        - name: cloudsql
          emptyDir:
        - name: ssl-certs
          hostPath:
            path: /etc/ssl/certs
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.11
        name: cloudsql-proxy
        command: ["/cloud_sql_proxy", "--dir=/cloudsql",
                  "-instances=tabb-168314:europe-west2:production=tcp:5432",
                  "-credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json"]
        volumeMounts:
          - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
            mountPath: /secrets/cloudsql
            readOnly: true
          - name: ssl-certs
            mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
          - name: cloudsql
            mountPath: /cloudsql
      - name: menu-service
        image: eu.gcr.io/tabb-168314/menu-service:develop
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
        - name: MICRO_BROKER
          value: "nats"
        - name: MICRO_BROKER_ADDRESS
          value: "nats.staging:4222"
        - name: MICRO_REGISTRY
          value: "kubernetes"
        - name: ENV
          value: "staging"
        - name: PORT
          value: "8080"
        - name: POSTGRES_HOST
          value: "127.0.0.1:5432"
        - name: POSTGRES_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: cloudsql-db-credentials
              key: username
        - name: POSTGRES_PASS
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: cloudsql-db-credentials
              key: password
        - name: POSTGRES_DB
          value: "menus"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

But unfortunately I'm getting this error when trying to update the deployment:

```
MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "kubernetes.io/secret/69b0ec99-baaf-11e7-82b8-42010a84010c-cloudsql-instance-credentials" (spec.Name: "cloudsql-instance-credentials") pod "69b0ec99-baaf-11e7-82b8-42010a84010c" (UID: "69b0ec99-baaf-11e7-82b8-42010a84010c") with: secrets "cloudsql-instance-credentials" not found
Error syncing pod, skipping: timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "staging"/"menu-service-1982520680-qzwzn". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[cloudsql-instance-credentials]
```

Have I missed something here?

Answer (score 4):

You are missing (at least) one of the secrets needed to start up this Pod, namely `cloudsql-instance-credentials`.

From https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-container-engine:

> You need two secrets to enable your Container Engine application to access the data in your Cloud SQL instance:
>
> - **The `cloudsql-instance-credentials` secret contains the service account.**
> - The `cloudsql-db-credentials` secret provides the proxy user account and password. (I think you have this created, I can't see an error message about this one)
>
> To create your secrets:
>
> Create the secret containing the Service Account which enables authentication to Cloud SQL:
>
> ```
> kubectl create secret generic cloudsql-instance-credentials \
>                    --from-file=credentials.json=[PROXY_KEY_FILE_PATH]
> ```
>
> [...]

The link above also describes how to create a GCP service account for this purpose, if you don't have one created already.

Comment: I did actually complete both of those steps successfully (5.1 and 5.2), so they should exist. Unless my service account has the wrong permissions, but I created it as an admin user. Strange! 

I might try the process end to end again, see if I missed anything, but I'm pretty sure I didn't.

Comment: Can you execute `kubectl get secret` to verify that the secret is indeed created? Double check the spelling, namespace, etc. This command should succeed: `kubectl get secret cloudsql-instance-credentials`

Comment: Both of those successfully return a secret, they both appear in the last when I go `kubectl get secret` also

Comment: In my case, the issue was exactly failing to include `--namespace=xyz` when creating secrets.